# Why doesnt mysql use the key for a simple select?

Tags: mysql, indexing, key

Here's what I did:

```
MariaDB []> explain select * from blabla where name like '%poor%';
+------+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table        | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+------+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | blabla       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 8358772 | Using where |
+------+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [bd]>show create table blabla;
| blabla | CREATE TABLE `blabla` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `name` (`name`(252))
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8372852 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

So if you watch: there's a key on 'name' and explain tells me "possible_keys" -> NULL. What shall I do to make this faster:

```
MariaDB []>select * from blabla where name like '%poor%';
********
********
491 rows in set (26.20 sec)
MariaDB []>WHAT??? 26 seconds on a 8 373 116 rows table? ARE YOU KIDDIN'?
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error
```

Comment: Search for 'poor%'. '%poor' cannot use an index. It's like trying to look up a word in a dictionary without knowing the first letter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, may I ask you to answer below? I thought MySQL would make an index, a tree, or something based on letters that are present, to find out fast.

Comment: I would, but someone's beaten me too it.

Comment: I love the dictionary / first letter analogy.  But I worry that, in less than a decade, you will have to explain the archaic concept of a "dictionary".  Hehe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL (and MariaDB) cannot make effective use of an index to satisfy the predicate.

```
name LIKE '%poor%'
```

Consider the possible value of `name` that would satisfy that condition, and where they could appear in the index. For example, values `'aaapoor'` and `'zzzpoor' satisfy the condition`. A value that satisfies the condition could appear *anywhere* in the index, as the first value/row in the index, or as the last value/row in the index, or anywhere in between.

So, MySQL has to evaluate that predicate for *every* row in the table. Every single row has to be checked.

MySQL can't use an index to eliminate *any* rows from being checked. The way that an index would improve performance for a predicate such as `col = 'foo'` is that MySQL can very quickly eliminate vast swaths of rows that do *not* need to be checked, because of where they appear in the index. MySQL can quickly eliminate a boatload of rows, and narrow in on the index pages that do need to be checked. That's how an index improves performance.

And MySQL can't do that with the predicate in your query. That's why no index is being used.

---

If there was a "covering" index for the query, MySQL might use that. For example, if you were selecting just the `name` column, MySQL could satisfy the query from just the index pages, without a need to visit the underlying data pages.

Or, if you had an "order by" on `name` (or a leading column or columns in an index), MySQL might make use of an index to avoid a "Using filesort" operation.

---

If you want to search for "words" that appear in a VARCHAR column, you might want to consider using a FULLTEXT index. In older versions of MySQL, those were supported only on MyISAM tables. Newer versions (>=5.6?) of MySQL support FULLTEXT indexes on InnoDB tables as well.

A fulltext search uses a different operation in the predicate (it's *not* a `LIKE` comparison.)