# Php to JavaScript: make a "string statistic" out of a string

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, string

I'm having more than 8 millions records with a column "name" and I have to find a way to optimize a search `select * from ... like '%string%'`.

The problem is that you can't use and index from this. So my idea is to make a "statistic" string like :

```
[char][number of chars][char][number of chars][char][number of chars]...
```

where `char` is the char found in the string and then the number of times it's in this string.

We can have strings like this:

```
name='Electroperro'
result='E01c01e02l01o02p01r03t01'
nom='Tanataka'
result='T01a04k01n01t01'
```

Well you got the idea. I've made it in Php like that:

```
function string_stat($tab) {
    $ret="";
    foreach ($tab as $key=>$c) {
        $ret.=sprintf("%s%02d", $key, $c);
    }
    return $ret;
}
echo 'nom='.var_export($nom,true)."\n";
$stat=array();
for ($i=0; $i<mb_strlen($nom); $i++) {
    $c=mb_substr($nom, $i, 1);
    if (!isset($stat[$c])) {
        $stat[$c]=0;
    }
    $stat[$c]++;
}
echo string_stat($stat)."\n";
```

I want to have exactly the same principle in JavaScript, for NodeJS, to do this with Mongoose. How would you do this?

Comment: I dont want to be rude, but you dont know the actual context and you make wrong assumptions. I'm looking for a way to make a **fast** search like `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE xx like '%yy%'`. There's no possible way of doing, read my question and answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30281033/why-doesnt-mysql-use-the-key-for-a-simple-select So the workaround I was thinking is in my question, plus later on a work on "SOUNDEX()" to make fast search if no result on the "statistic string" were found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in this case you must use some special search engines like `Sphinx` or `elasticsearch`. It will make search immediately, because it was developed specially for this. I think do it in MySQL (or other DB) is not good approach.